# HTML <input type='file'> File Selection Event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Let's say we have this code:

```
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='userFile'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='upload_btn' value='upload'>
</form>
```

which results in this:

[image: image showing browse and upload button]

When the user clicks the 'Browse...' button, a file search dialog box is opened:

[image: image showing a file search dialog box with a file selected]

The user will select the file either by double-clicking the file or by clicking the 'Open' button .

Is there a Javascript Event that I can use to be notified after the file is selected?

Comment: What a funky old windows UI !

Comment: @El-Burritos this was posted in 2010; of course, it's an old Windows UI:D

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Listen to the change event.

```js
 document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    document.body.append('You selected ' + e.target.files[0].name);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input">
```

Comment: we gonna write it where.. in javascript script tags

Comment: yes in script tags, or you could add it as an attribute (`<input type="file" onchange="..." />`) although this is not recommended.

Comment: Note that in IE7 and 8 that the 'change' event doesn't bubble up to the form event. You need to put your listener on the <input> tag.

Comment: What about if a user needs to "reload" a file? onchange will not trigger, but it should still reload as if it was loading it for the first time.

Comment: Note, this doesn't work if the user picks the same file more than once in a row since the file didn't change.

Comment: Make sure to empty out the value after onchange event is handled, otherwise onchange wont get triggered next time if the user decides to choose different file after the initial selection

Comment: @Anurag , I want to identify when a file is successfully uploaded, is there any way to find that out? onChange gets triggered if any file is selected to be uploaded.

Comment: If you also want it to trigger on cancel or the same file, you should listen to the `input` event instead of the `change` event

Comment: This doesn't work if the user selects the same file they had selected before.

Answer (score 64):

When you have to reload the file, you can erase the value of input. Next time you add a file, 'on change' event will trigger.

```
document.getElementById('my_input').value = null;
// ^ that just erase the file path but do the trick
```

Comment: That works fine but be aware of weird IE <11 behavior. It doesn't allow you to change input's value, so most likely you will need a workaround.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011644/how-to-reset-clear-file-input

Answer (score 20):

jQuery way:

```
$('input[name=myInputName]').change(function(ev) {

    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 14):

That's the way I did it with pure JS:

```js
var files = document.getElementById('filePoster');
var submit = document.getElementById('submitFiles');
var warning = document.getElementById('warning');
files.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (files.files.length > 10) {
    submit.disabled = true;
    warning.classList += "warn"
    return;
  }
  warning.classList -= "warn";
  submit.disabled = false;
});
```

```css
#warning {
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s all;
}

#warning.warn {
    color: red;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<section id="shortcode-5" class="shortcode-5 pb-50">
    <p id="warning">Please do not upload more than 10 images at once.</p>
    <form class="imagePoster" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/gallery/imagePoster" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
    <input id="filePoster" type="file" class="form-control" name="photo" required="required" multiple="multiple" />
        <button id="submitFiles" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 7):

Though it is an old question, it is still a valid one.

**Expected behavior:**

- Show selected file name after upload.
- Do not do anything if the user clicks `Cancel`.
- Show the file name even when the user selects the same file.

**Code with a demonstration:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>File upload event</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userFile" id="userFile"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload_btn" value="upload">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("userFile").onchange = function(e) {
      alert(this.value);
      this.value = null;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Explanation:**

- The `onchange` event handler is used to handle any change in file selection event.
- The `onchange` event is triggered only when the value of an element is changed. So, when we select the same file using the `input` field the event will not be triggered. To overcome this, I set `this.value = null;` at the end of the `onchange` event function. It sets the file path of the selected file to `null`. Thus, the `onchange` event is triggered even at the time of the same file selection.

Answer (score 6):

The Change event gets called even if you click on cancel..

Comment: it would help if you would provide some code to explain your answer, since there is no change event mentioned in the Questions code snippet

Comment: I think @anthony is referring to the following scenario: Select a file. 
Now open the file selector again, but this time click on Cancel. Since no file was selected the second time, the file input control resets, thus changing its initial selection, and the change event is fired.

Comment: I tried it on Chrome 83 and the event doesn't get fired when I click on the Cancel button. This answer is pretty old and I guess it must've been fixed, at least on Chrome.