# how to reset (clear) file input

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, file-io

how can I reset file input in IE, I used the following and it worked in chrome and FF but not IE

`fileInputElement.value=""`

what's the alternative in IE ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `fileInputElement` is on its own in the form `fileInputForm`, you can do:

```
window.fileInputForm.reset();
```

Otherwise for IE you'll have to replace the element with a clone:

```
fileInputElement.parentNode.replaceChild(
    fileInputElement.cloneNode(true), 
    fileInputElement
);
```

Comment: code for IE did work for reset but it lost all its events. :(

Comment: Use deferred event handlers so that doesn't happen (eg jQuery.on handler).

Comment: Worked for me with IE10 ... a nice simple solution.

Answer (score 7):

#### SOLUTION

The following code worked for me with jQuery. It works in every browser and allows to preserve events and custom properties.

```
var $el = $(fileInputElement);
$el.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
$el.unwrap();
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/yfeo529g/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

- [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351234/3549014)
- [How to reset file input with JavaScript](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/how-to-reset-file-input-with-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried many solutions on SO. Most don't work. Here's the one that works. -- and in just 3 lines. <3

Answer (score 5):

Cross-Browser solution by @Gyrocode.com in vanilla JS:

```
var clearFileInput = function (input) {
  if (!input) {
    return;
  }

  // standard way - works for IE 11+, Chrome, Firefox, webkit Opera
  input.value = null;

  if (input.files && input.files.length && input.parentNode) {
    // workaround for IE 10 and lower, pre-webkit Opera

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    input.parentNode.insertBefore(form, input);

    form.appendChild(input);
    form.reset();

    form.parentNode.insertBefore(input, form);
    input.parentNode.removeChild(form);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't reset the File input by itself. What you can do is wrap your File input in a `<form id="form_id">` tag and reset the form. With jQuery you can do `$('#form_id')[0].reset();` and in JavaScript you can do `document.getElementById('form_id').reset()`.

Comment: Any idea why document.getElementById('form_id').reset() works, document.getElementById('form_id')[0].reset() doesnt, and why jquery requires the [0]? (thanks by the way, you saved me atleast 30 minutes)

Comment: `getElementById()` doesn't return an array, so there is no index `[0]` in the result. jQuery does return an array of objects, so when you specify `[0]` you are retrieving the first element in the returned set.

Answer (score 0):

With **IE 10** I resolved the problem with :

```
    var file = document.getElementById("file-input");
    file.removeAttribute('value');
    file.parentNode.replaceChild(file.cloneNode(true),file);
```

where :

```
<input accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" id="file-input" type="file"/>
```