# Empty input type file doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this simple javascript code:

```
$("input[type='file']").attr("value", "");
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE (I tried in IE9)

What's the good approach to empty the input type file value ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to reset (clear) file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011644/how-to-reset-clear-file-input)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some restriction on input type = file

You can read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx)

This seems to be working in IE8, IE9

```
$("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
```

To test in IE8 I changed the compatibility mode in developer tool to IE8

Edit:

As for many IE hacks I think this is better

```
    if($.browser.msie){
        $("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
    } else {
        $("input[type='file']").val('');
    }
```

Comment: works fine with `$("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));`

Comment: glad :) If IE continues the same way wont be too long to see this in common (https://4ormat.com/signup) (check this page in IE ;))

Comment: LOL, IE becomes ugly, very ugly

Comment: The same issue is in Opera. But this solution doesn't work for Opera:/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery docs says](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: I tried now with prop like `$("input[type='file']").prop("value", "");` but not works in IE9...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299052/jquery-get-the-file-name-selected-from-input-type-file.