# IE 9 jQuery not setting input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, internet-explorer-9, file-io

my question is simple:

I have an input file field, and i want to limit it to only accept .GIFs via Jquery , and if the format is wrong, set the input value blank.

The problem is that on IE9, the `.val('')` does not work. Any ideas?

My jQuery:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    switch (val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()) {
    case 'gif':
        break;
    default:
        // error message here
        alert("Wrong Format");
        $(this).val('');
        break;
    }
});​
```

Comment: I think from IE8 File Upload field is read-only...

Comment: AFAIK the file input is `readonly` you can't change it's value programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i did not know it was a readonly field on IE8/9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From IE8 it is readonly try:

```
$("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
```

Picked from here :  [SO Anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327860/empty-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really helped me. Although the name of the file remains in the input field, in the 'logic' part the input is empty.