# resetting input file using $(this).val("") not working with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE 9 jQuery not setting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567469/ie-9-jquery-not-setting-input-value)

I would like to reset the input field if it matches some conditions using `$(this).val("");`:

```
$(".checkimgextension").on("change", function () {

var file = $(this).val();

if (some conditions){
  alert("wrong:...");
  $(this).val("");
}
```

With Firefox the field is set to `""`, but with IE the field does not change as expected. Am using the right function `.val("")`?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/xNsEZ/1/

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or it didn't happen.

Comment: In your title, you say "file" -- you mean really mean `input type="file"`?

Comment: Guys it's very likely to be a "file" input, and you can't set its value from JavaScript in IE.

Answer (score 8):

Refer to this: [IE 9 jQuery not setting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567469/ie-9-jquery-not-setting-input-value)

```
$("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
```

So in your case:

```
$(this).replaceWith($(this).clone(true));
```

instead of the `$(this).val("");` line.

**UPDATE:**

In order to take advantage of browsers that allow you to modify the `input:file` element, I would use something like this:

```
$(".checkimgextension").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (some conditions) {
        alert("wrong:...");
        $this.val("");
        var new_val = $this.val();
        if (new_val !== "") {
            $this.replaceWith($this.clone(true));
        }
    }
});
```

That way, it attempts to just set the value to empty at first, and if that doesn't succeed, use the `replaceWith` method.

Comment: Updated to avoid `replaceWith` when possible