# In Extjs 3.x input type file text field reset is not working in IE8(Extjs)EXTJS*3.2

Tags: extjs3

extjs× 6627,3.x version, In mozilla browser reset is working for inputType :'file', but its not working for IE8 Browser and this is my code,

```
xtype :'textfield',
name:'Policy_fileUpload',
id :title+'_uploadFile',
inputType :'file',
fieldLabel :'Upload File and Location<font color=red>*</font>',
blankText :'Please choose a file',
anchor :'100%',
required :true,
autoShow :true
```

now am resetting this field by using the reset property

```
xtype:'button',extjs× 6627
id:title+'cancelButton',
width:100,
text:'Cancel',
listeners : {
   'click':function(){
       Ext.getCmp(title+'_uploadFile').reset();
       }
```

help me to solve this Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a security 'feature' in IE8. Here are related topics where solution for this problem is given using jQuery:

[Empty input type file doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327860/empty-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-ie)

[Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery/1043969)

Both of them suggest something in the lines of recreating the input field. To do that in ExtJS 3.x, you may try something like this:

```
listeners : {
    'click':function(){
        var uploadField = Ext.getCmp('_uploadFile');                
        if (Ext.isIE8) {                
            var cfg = uploadField.initialConfig;
            uploadField.destroy();
            var parentCt = Ext.getCmp('parentContainer');
            parentCt.insert(0, cfg);
            parentCt.doLayout();
        } else {
            uploadField.reset();
        }

    } 
}
```

Also, it seems that IE9 behaves in the same way. So you may want to have `if (Ext.isIE)` instead of `if (Ext.isIE8)`.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful for me, but here what you are mentioning as a Ext.getCmp('parentContainer');,, why am asking this means while running the script its throwing undefined error so i cant set the value for var parentCt.

Comment: 'parentContainer' is the id of a container in which uploadField has been placed. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/UAAH3/ .

Actually, referencing components by their id property is a bad idea in bigger application. I used it here as I thought it was pretty obvious what I meant.

Comment: Very Thanks medvarztis while executing below code am using one alert to find what it is comin in the parentContainer but its displaying that as a undefined, ihave attached the code below... thanks in advance
if (Ext.isIE) {
var cfg = uploadField.initialConfig;
uploadField.setRawValue(' ');
alert('cfg value'+ Ext.get('parentContainer'));
if(Ext.get('parentContainer') == null){
Ext.getCmp(title+'_uploadFile').setVisible(true);
}
var parentCt = Ext.is('parentContainer');
parentCt.insert(0, cfg);
parentCt.doLayout();
} else {
uploadField.reset();
}

Comment: Ok, sorry for confusion. 'parentCointainer' is an ID of the parent component. You actually need to REPLACE IT WITH YOUR OWN ID. If you have a panel (or any other component) with ID 'myPanel', inside which you have your upload field with id "title+'_uploadField'", then you need to replace 'parentContainer' with 'myPanel' (i.e. your id of that component).

Comment: Very Very thanks medvarztis,, its working fine for me and it was really helpful....thanks againg :-)