# Refresh input type file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, file, input

I'm working on an Angular project.

When I import several documents I have the message "two documents". nothing problematic.
[image]

The problem arises when I press the delete button that I created.
It allows to empty my list but to display there is always written "two documents"

I wish I had that. like when we get to the page for the first time ("no file selected") :

### [image]

How could I do to reload this input without reloading the page?

My code :

html :

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="pj">Pièce jointe</label>
          <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <input type="file" name="pj" id="pj" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple>
            <button type="button" (click)="clearFile()" class="btn btn-link">
              <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

ts :

```
 clearFile() {
 this.message.files = null;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011644/how-to-reset-clear-file-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a reactive form, you can just call `reset()` on the form control.

component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">  
  <input type="file" multiple formControlName="files" />
  <button type="button" (click)="clearFile()">
    Delete
  </button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    files: new FormControl('')
  });
}

clearFile() {
  this.form.get('files').reset();
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-huvm38

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ViewChild` to access the input in your component. First, you need to add `#someValue` to your input so you can read it in the component:

`<input  #myInput type="file" name="pj" id="pj" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple`>

Then in your component you need to import `ViewChild` from `@angular/core`:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Then you use `ViewChild` to access the input from template:

```
// ng 8 @ViewChild('myInput', {static: false}) myInput: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;
```

Now you can use `myInput` to reset the selected file because it's a reference to input with `#myInput`, for example create method `reset()` that will be called on `click` event of your button:

```
reset() {
    console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.files);
    this.myInput.nativeElement.value = "";
    console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.files);
}
```