# Is there a way in JS / React to execute code if input[type="file"] has a file uploaded

Tags: javascript

i want to execute some code only if user has clicked on "add file" (when we use an input type file in html) and selected a file. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can work with the `input` event like this:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

You can of course modify this to suit your requirement. This example is from the Mozilla documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528376/2570277) answer which you may also find useful. It works with the `change` event.